# How can I take the text from UITextFields in UITableViewCells in a UITableView and put them into an array (Swift 3)?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

I am making a calculator app which involves a UITableView that allows users to enter variables before clicking a calculator UIButton to perform the calculation. The reason I want to use a UITableView and not just plan UITextFields is because my app includes many different calculations which means that the number of UITableViewCells changes based on the user's selection.

I was hoping to find a way to obtain an array of the visible UITextField values whenever the calculator UIButton is pressed. The UITableView class seems to be more geared towards entering data into the cells rather than obtaining. Is there a different approach I could be using? I am using one storyboard with Swift 3 files.

Comment: How many UITextFields you will have in table view ? Can you share a screenshot of the screen with tableview how it looks like ?

Comment: You work with data, not with views, remember that, once user enter something into the textfield in a cell, store it right away in your data source on `endEditting`, and later get the value from there

Comment: Can you provide the details of the Controller class. I normally back the UITableView with an array that I can then read and write to. The array index and the UITableViewCell indexes match up so I can identify each row in the UITableView against an item in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to make a lot of assumptions here since you did not provide some sample code.

Lets say that you are using a `UIViewController` that has a `UITableView` inside it

```
class CalculatorViewController
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var values: [Double] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Now you have a basic viewController but the compiler will say that CalculatorViewController does not conform to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`. Let's fix that

```
extension CalculatorViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // return your number of sections, let say it's one
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Let's say you only have 3 cells at the moment
        return 3
   }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCustomInputFieldCell") as! YourCustomInputFieldCell
        return cell
    }

}
```

Let's fix the `UITableViewDelegate` error

```
extension CalculatorViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    // This one gets called each time a cell will be displayed (as it says)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = cell as? YourCustomInputTextField {

            // I assume that you expose your cell's input field
            // By setting a tag on the input field you can
            // distinguish it from other inputs

            cell.input.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.input.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Again the compiler will complain that `CalculatorViewController` does not conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`. Let's fix that too.

```
extension CalculatorViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // Here you can check the tag of the textField
        // and update the values array accordingly

        // You should probably convert the string that you get to
        // the number format that you want
        return true
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. UITextFieldDelegate was the bit I was missing.

Comment: @Kalchi25 you are welcome! feel free to accept the answer if it helped you